# pip2 causes ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'pip2') not found

Tags: python-2.7, pip, homebrew, macos-sierra

I installed python 2 by

```
brew install python
```

I can localise pip2 but not use it. In the terminal i get an error as:

```
elenama@s2078:~$ pip2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip2", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip2')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 570, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2750, in load_entry_point
    raise ImportError("Entry point %r not found" % ((group, name),))
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'pip2') not found

elenama@s2078:~$ which pip2
/usr/local/bin/pip2
```

I uninstalled the local python by `sudo pip uninstall pip`. I also uninstalled python and reinstalled it.

(pip3 works, btw.)

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, fixed it by running this

```
python2 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with current Homebrew Python 2 install. I just installed yesterday and have exactly the same issue (python3 is fine).

I don't have a solution as such, but am able to create a virtualenv with PyCharm, activate that environment, and use pip to install stuff as normal. PyCharm doesn't need virtualenv package to do this.

Since one should use virtualenv (or equivalent) all of the time anyway for real work, it is not so bad a problem that you cannot add packages outside of one. But I think I will file an issue on https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core to see if someone can fix or explain why it is not working.

Also we should all be using Python 3 for everything! This is just one more reminder, as if we needed one.

Answer (score 0):

Need To Install Python2.7 From Here . then restart terminal :
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2714/